# Search Filter using Input and DIV

Tags: javascript

I created this simple JS code to Filter the "rows" and search by the name writed in the input.

- When i write in the input he make a search, but always the same search.

Can someone help..

This is the input.

```
<input id='myInput' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Pesquisar por R-ID...'>
```

This is the row for looping using WHILE()

```
echo "<div class='row' id='table_row'><div class='col-md-12 track clearfix'><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'>R-$repair_id - <h4 class=''>$repair_model</h4> <a href='repairlist.php?id=$repair_id' class='btn btn-default btn-xs move right-id'> Ver Ficha</a> <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs move right-id'>Nova Entrada</a></div><div class='panel-body'><p><small>$repair_date</small></p><p>$repair_desc_problem</p></div></div></div></div>";
```

This is JS script to filter and find...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("#table_row").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my Codepen snippet that perfectly fit for your use case. Here the User can enter a name and the results will be shown after filtering the database with search text.
Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/pro_animator/pen/zJpZxd

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById("searchDropdown");
var resultsElement = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var lowerCaseData, filteredData;
var data = [
  {
    name: "Satya",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "Rahul",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Ronny",
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name: "Abc ",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Broady",
    age: 27
  }
];

inputElement.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  while (resultsElement.hasChildNodes()) {
        resultsElement.removeChild(resultsElement.firstChild);
  }
  filteredData = data.filter(function(person) {
    return person.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  });
  populateDropdown(filteredData);
})

// Function to create search result dom.
function populateDropdown(result) {
  var liElement, textNode;
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  result.forEach(function(resultRow) {
     liElement = document.createElement("li");
     textNode = document.createTextNode(resultRow.name + "(age:" + resultRow.age + ")");
     liElement.appendChild(textNode);
     frag.appendChild(liElement);
   })
  resultsElement.appendChild(frag);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #42bad2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
input {
/*   width: 200px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
  
}
ul li {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 5px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="searchDropdown" type="text" placeholder="Type a name(ex: satya)"/>
  <ul id="searchResults"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that's perfect. but in the data i have to put the PHP data... só... i have one option.. Try to put the DIV #table_row in the data... will work?